# Android What is the cache key in the "setAnimationFromJson" method of Lottie?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, lottie

I want to play a **Lottie animation** from JSON string **programmatically**. Lottie library provides a function to set the animation, which has two parameters. The first one has been deprecated, and the second one has the cache key, which can be nullable. What is the **cache key** exactly?

[image]

Comment: Lottie do cache of animation that you load and you can provide key to it .. here is source code of it https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/blob/ee942249214dd6bb1540b746ca0b678a6382b5ee/lottie/src/main/java/com/airbnb/lottie/LottieAnimationView.java

Answer (score 0):

In the `setAnimationFromJson()` method of [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/issues/1270), the cache key is a unique identifier that is used to cache the `LottieComposition` object that is created from the JSON string.

The cache key is an optional parameter that can be used to specify a custom key for caching the LottieComposition object. If no cache key is specified, a default cache key will be generated based on the source of the JSON string.

```
String json = "{...}"; // JSON string
String cacheKey = "my_animation"; // Custom cache key

LottieAnimationView animationView = findViewById(R.id.animation_view);
animationView.setAnimationFromJson(json, cacheKey);
```

In this example, the setAnimationFromJson() method is called with a JSON string and a custom cache key. The [LottieComposition](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/blob/master/lottie/src/main/java/com/airbnb/lottie/LottieComposition.java) object that is created from the JSON string will be cached using the custom cache key.

If no cache key is specified, the Lottie library will generate a default cache key based on the source of the JSON string. For example, if the JSON string is loaded from a file in the `res/raw or assets directory`, a default cache key will be generated based on the file name